# Impact of Chrome deprecating direct access to private network endpoints on MS edge browser

Tags: google-chrome, networking, microsoft-edge

google chrome is deprecating direct access to private network endpoints from public websites as part of the Private Network Access (PNA) specification as per the developers blog below:
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/

since chrome and MS edge are built on the same engine would this also affect this feature on MS edge?? would it be deprecated on the new release of MS edge?

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer below? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Edge and Chrome are both based on chromium, and I think Edge has also applied this feature. From the doc, we can know that:

> To limit the effects on websites that do not already support preflights, the timeout is restricted to 200 milliseconds in Chrome 104. The restriction is only applied in warning mode. The special timeout limit would be removed after enabling the enforce mode by switching "Respect the result of Private Network Access preflights" to "Enabled" in `chrome://flags` and the default limit is 5 seconds.

If you open `edge://flags/` and search **Respect the result of Private Network Access preflights**, you'll also find this flag which means Edge also has this feature:

[image]